# How to run node app from sub-directory with .env variables of that sub-directory?

Tags: node.js, directory, environment-variables

I have a Node.js App called app.js and its stored in the directory B.

To run this script correctly it needs enviroment variables. These are stored in a file called .env, which is also in directory B.

In my app.js the env-variables are loaded via `require("dotenv").config();`
and I can then access them with e.g. `process.env.SOME_VAR`

So if I am currently located in directory B, I can just use `node app` and my app will execute just fine.

But if I go to the parent directory A and try to run my app via

`node ./B/app`

it will not execute, because it seems to have no access to the enviroment variables of the .env file.

So, my question is, how can I run my script from its parent folder, if I want to keep the .env file in the same directory?

Comment: How do you load the `.env` file? Can you share some code?

Comment: I edited my post. I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load the the content of the environment variable i.e.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// ...

// Then go ahead to load the .env file content into process.env
dotenv.config({ path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars' });
```

Comment: Can I also use the relative path for the .env file? Like './.env'

Comment: @nexus186 Yes you can.

Comment: @nexus186 i think relative path does not work unless you preload as shown here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#preload

Answer (score 1):

you can set path using `{path : '../.env'}`.

```
require('dotenv').config({path : '../.env'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant! it worked for me, I put my .env inside /vars folder
and used this line

```
require('dotenv').config({path : 'vars/.env'});
```

Instead of this line

```
require("dotenv").config();
```